# Prevent a zpl file from being printed twice

Tags: printing, zpl

I have a program that generates a text file with zpl code in it.  The file is supposed to contain unique barcodes that I only want to be printed once.  Is there a way to either guarantee a unique barcode or prevent a file from being printed more than once.

Comment: Yes, lots of ways. What have you tried?

Comment: When I send my vendor the zpl file to print they are not supposed to reprint that file. In that file I will have a sequence of barcodes from 10000-10100. Since ZPL doesn't store any veriables/ sessions the second time they go to reprint the file it will just reprint the same barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be far to complex for a ZPL-only solution.
Instead, your barcode sequence(s) and printing them should be handled by some sort of programming logic/algorithm which stores the used and unused barcodes in a database or textfile.